# Uploading multiple images in React

Tags: reactjs

I would like to upload multiple images to send them off.

I tried this two ways in `handleChange` but the `formdata` is always empty.
I also want to know how to display the image in the react

```
state = { files: []}

fileChangeHandler = (e) => {
this.setState({ files: e.target.files })
this.setState({ files: [...this.state.files, ...e.target.files] })}


handleSubmit(event) {let fileData = new FormData();
fileData.append('files', this.state.files);
    uploadClaimFile(response.data.id, fileData);}
```

the input

```
  <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.fileChangeHandler} />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way to append to a `state` array without directly modifying it is to make a shallow copy of the array, add the new items, and then replace the array using `setState`:

```js
fileChangeHandler = (e) => {
  const files = [...this.state.files]; // Spread syntax creates a shallow copy
  files.push(...e.target.files); // Spread again to push each selected file individually
  this.setState({ files });
}
```

As for uploading the files, when appending to a `FormData` object you must append the files one at a time:

```js
handleSubmit(event) {
  const fileData = new FormData();
  this.state.files.forEach((file) => fileData.append('files[]', file));
  // ... Submit fileData
}
```

Note: The use of `[]` in naming the data is in accordance with [PHP naming conventions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Example) when uploading multiple files.

#### Edit

To answer your last question about displaying multiple uploaded files, you would want to write a method to take those files, create URLs that tie them back to the document, and display them. *However*, created URLs must be revoked to prevent memory leaks. Thus, it might be a good idea to store them in state to keep track of them, so you can implement it like this:

```js
this.state = { files: [], urls: [] };

setFileUrls(files) {
  const urls = files.map((file) => URL.createObjectURL(file));
  if(this.state.urls.length > 0) {
    this.state.urls.forEach((url) => URL.revokeObjectURL(url));
  }
  this.setState({ urls });
}

displayUploadedFiles(urls) {
  return urls.map((url, i) => <img key={i} src={url}/>);
}
```

Call `setFileUrls` in your `onChange` handler, and call `displayUploadedFiles` in the render method:

```js
render() {
  return (
    // ... other stuff
    {this.state.urls.length > 0 && 
    <Fragment>{this.displayUploadedFiles(this.state.urls)}</Fragment>
    }
    // ... more stuff
  );
}
```

Multiple adjacent elements should be wrapped in a parent element, which can be a `div` or a React [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Comment: thanks so much that's so helpful and it's work.. about displaying the image that help me to show a preview after uploading but i need to display it from database, it work in the same way ?

Comment: Usually a database would store images as  `Buffer` array, so when you request those images you will have to convert that array to a base64 string, which will be the `src` for your `img` tag but should be prepended with `data:image/jpeg;base64,`.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore this npm module [React Drop Zone.](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone)